# Disable USB 3 (use ehci instead of xhci) on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: usb, ubuntu, kernel

I'm trying to disable USB3 entirely on my raspberry pi 4 running Ubuntu server but I can't find a way to do it. Some things that I've tried are:

- Blacklisting xhci - doesn't work because it's a builtin module.
- Using setpci as documented [here](https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-force-a-usb-3-0-port-to-work-in-usb-2-0-mode-in-linux/) to disable it - this command doesn't work because `-H1` isn't an argument in the version of `setpci` that is available. Without `-H1` it doesn't seem to do anything.
- Disabling USB 3 at some lower level - normally you can do this in the bios but I think the pi doesn't have a bios, I couldn't find any other way to do this.

Is there anything else I can try?

More context: I'm hoping that this will allow me to use more than 32 USB devices as explained [here](http://marc.merlins.org/perso/linux/post_2018-12-20_Getting-Around-USB3-xhci-32-Device-Limit-_Max-number-of-devices-this-xHCI-host-supports-is-32_.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
initcall_blacklist=xhci_hcd_init
```

to your kernel parameters (`/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`). Or maybe `xhci_init_driver`. You'll have to experiment here.

Also take a look at the "quirks" available in `drivers/usb/host/xhci.h`. Specifically, if this is an Intel-only limitation, you could try `XHCI_NEC_HOST`. There's also `XHCI_EP_LIMIT_QUIRK`, though I honestly have no idea what it does.

If the experiments are fruitless, you'll have to build a custom kernel.

Comment: Oh, I actually tried this too but Ubuntu on the raspberry pi doesn't seem to have a `/boot/cmdline.txt` file. Do you know what the equivalent place is?

Comment: @dshepherd Not really. Find out which bootloader you are using (`grub`?) and how to provide it with custom kernel parameters.

Comment: Turns out that it uses a modified version of U-boot which provides a `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` which works like the normal raspberry pi `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Comment: That particular blacklist didn't do anything but I searched the kernel source code for `__init` and xhci and found `xhci_pci_init`. Blacklisting that definitely stopped it from using xhci for the USB ports but unfortunately it doesn't use ehci instead, so I guess this is a dead end. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I also had a look at the quirks config that you mentioned but from the comments it sounds like that would give me a completely broken USB system rather than a working USB system with a larger number of devices.